# Insert from back : Linked List

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

I read the code from this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24684/How-to-create-Linked-list-using-C-C, but it gave me segmentation fault and I don't quite get it.

*I modified it to my struct

```
struct Node
{
    int type;
    char cmd[256];
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *head = NULL;

void insert(int val, char arr[])
{
    struct Node *temp1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *temp2 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp1 = head;
    while(temp1->next != NULL)
        temp1 = temp1->next;

    temp2->type = val;
    strcpy(temp2->cmd, arr);

    temp2->next = NULL;
    temp1->next = temp2;
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

OK, this problem is solved. Thx Guyz '^'! Do you know by any chance how to put charcters " (ASCII 34) into a printf string? (e.g. if I do printf("Print this "sentence""); it would give me error in sentence, cut I casted another set of "" inside a "". Thx a bunch.

Comment: Which line caused the seg-fault?

Comment: You dont need to allocate memory for `temp1` or you will have memory leak. `struct Node *temp1 = head` is fine.

Comment: Can you tell us the content of `struct Node` ? (and what is `cmd` member)

Comment: I just looked at the content of the linked page, and it's Absolutely Terrible.  Do not use it.

Comment: where's `head` defined?  Are you initializing it anywhere?

Comment: Try to use `strncpy` : `strncpy(temp2->cmd, arr, 256);`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Any suggestion? :D or how do make it so that it inserts from back?

Comment: @Michael I don't think it's strcpy problem, it works fine if i use that for insert from front

Comment: @LarsChung, so maybe `head` is your problem, is it correctly pointing to the head of your list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will correct the memory leak and check that head is valid.
If you still had the segmentation fault, you should run a debugger to know exactly what is going.

```
void insert(int val, char arr[])
{
    struct Node *temp2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp2->type = val;
    strcpy(temp2->cmd, arr);
    temp2->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
      //list is empty, head must points on the created node
      head = temp2;
    }
    else {
      struct Node *temp1 = head;

      while(temp1->next != NULL)
        temp1 = temp1->next;

      temp1->next = temp2;
   }
}
```

**EDIT** : Now, this function should handle any case, even if `head` is null. (when list is empty)

Comment: OK, this problem is solved. Thx! Do you know by any chance how to put charcters " (ASCII 34) into a printf string? (e.g. if I do printf("Print this "sentence""); it would give me error in sentence, cut I casted another set of "" inside a "".

Comment: @LarsChung yes just add the escape character : `printf("Print this \"sentence\"");`

Comment: nvm, i got it, I can do %c and put the ascii value there. thx anyways '^'

Comment: @LarsChung, if you want to add any ascii character, dont use %c, you can do this with `\x(hex ascii value)` : `printf("\x58\x59\x5A");` will print `XYZ`

Answer (score 3):

First, you're failing to set the head pointer on initial insert. This can be done with a simple head-check, though it isn't needed if the insertion loop is setup correctly. Second, you're leaking memory. This isn't Java. overwriting a pointer holding the address of a dynamic allocation is as good as throwing memory out the window.

This is one way to do this without burying an `if (head == NULL)` special case in your insertion code. Contrary to popular opinion, you don't need that special case if you do it like this:

```
void insert(int val, char arr[])
{
    struct Node **pp = &head;
    while (*pp)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    *pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
    (*pp)->next = NULL;
    (*pp)->type = val;
    strcpy((*pp)->cmd, arr);
}
```

Just make sure `head` is initialized to NULL before doing any insertions, which it looks like you're doing correctly by looking at your updated post.

Finally, [don't cast `malloc()` results in C programs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `head` before you run the first insert:

```
/* This should go in main or some init function, before the first insert */
head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
head->next = NULL;
```

Comment: When i do insert from front, and I leave head as it is in my question, it works fine, any reason why it needs to be done like this for insert from back?

Comment: @LarsChung because of `while(temp1->next != NULL)` check (which attempts to dereference a null pointer).  I suspect your front-insert doesn't attempt to access `head->next`

Comment: oh yeah it's kinda fixed, but there's still some logic error in it I think, i get an extra node.... I put in 3 strings, but it gives me 4 nodes...

Comment: @LarsChung thats because you don't need to set an initial node. You can do this with an initial head pointer of NULL if it is checked correctly.

Comment: @LarsChung, check my answer, it handle the case when the list is empty and do not add extra node.

Answer (score 0):

See the link you referred, there also has a test file, http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=24684, it will tell why you get this error, When insert from the back, it will first check the head if it is null and allocate space for the first element.

> Blockquote

```
1  #include<iostream>
  2  
  3  using namespace std;
  4  
  5  typedef struct node
  6  {
  7      int data;   // will store information
  8      node *next; // the reference to the next node
  9  };
 10  
 11  
 12  int main()
 13  {
 14      node *head = NULL;  //empty linked list
 15      int info = 0, node_number = 0,  counter = 0;
 16      char ch;
 17  
 18      do{
 19          cout<<"\n\n";
 20          cout<<"0.Quit\n";
 21          cout<<"1.Insert at first\n";
 22          cout<<"2.Traverse\n";
 23          cout<<"3.Insert at last\n";
 24          cout<<"4.Insert after specified number of node\n";
 25          cout<<"5.Delete at first node\n";
 26          cout<<"6.Delete at last node\n";
 27          cout<<"7.Delete specified number of node\n";
 28          cout<<"8.Sort nodes\n";
 29  
 30          cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
 31          cin>>ch;
 32  
 33      switch(ch)
 34      {
 35  
 36      case '0': break;
 37  
 38      case '1': ....

  .....  case '3':{
           **// check linked list is empty**
           if(head==NULL)
           {
               cout<<"ENTER ANY NUMBER:";
               cin>>info;                        // take input data
               cout<<"Input data: "<<info;

               node *temp;                     // create a temporary node
               temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate space for node
               temp->data = info;               // store data(first field)
               temp->next = NULL;               // second field will be null
               head = temp;                    // transfer the address of 'temp' to 'head'
               counter++;
           }

           else
           {
               cout<<"ENTER ANY NUMBER:";
               cin>>info;                        // take input data
               cout<<"Input data: "<<info;
               node *temp1;                        // create a temporary node
               temp1=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));  // allocate space for node
               temp1 = head;                   // transfer the address of 'head' to 'temp'
               while(temp1->next!=NULL)         // go to the last node
                   temp1 = temp1->next;         //tranfer the address of 'temp->next' to 'temp'

               node *temp;                 // create a temporary node
               temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));// allocate space for node
               temp->data = info;               // store data(first field)
               temp->next = NULL;               // second field will be null(last node)
               temp1->next = temp;              // 'temp' node will be the last node
               break;
            }
   }
```

Comment: it is similar in manipulating the list,  I can see only difference in input/output function call, it is easy to convert.

Comment: you'd better write your function to handle two two situations: AddToHead() and AddToBack(), not just insert()