# Insert in back of Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to get a working function that I can call insert_back and it will insert the value to the end of the list

so far I have the code and I think I have become stumped.

```
    template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert_back( const Object& data ) {
    ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, head->getNext() );
        if (!head) {

            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        while (head->getNext()) {
            continue;
        }
        head->setNext( newnode );
    }
```

This returns nothing and chokes the program when I call insert_back

the .H file

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include "ListNode.h"
#include "ListIterator.h"

namespace cs20 {

template <class Object>
class List {
    public:
    List();
    List( const List& rhs );
    ~List();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isIncreasing() const;
    void makeEmpty();
    ListIterator<Object> zeroth() const;
    ListIterator<Object> first() const;
    void insert( const Object& data,
                 const ListIterator<Object> &iter );
    void insert( const Object& data );
    void insert_back( const Object& data );
    ListIterator<Object> findPrevious( const Object& data ) const;
    void remove( const Object& data );

    const List& operator =( const List& rhs );
    const List& operator <<( const List& rhs );
private:
    ListNode<Object> * head;

};

}
#endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert from back : Linked List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076294/insert-from-back-linked-list)

Comment: Can you please provide more detail about what you've tried so far, what specific errors you're getting, and what your test code is? We can't necessarily reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change you code to this:

```
ListNode<Object>* lastNode = head;
while (lastNode->getNext())
    lastNode = lastNode->getNext();
lastNode->setNext( newnode );
```

Comment: Thank you!

Only thing is that, while this works.... It repeats the list of numbers infinitely until i have to manually stop the program..

Comment: than you have error in node adding logic somewhere which created node-loop, when next points to itself instead of next or NULL, also check comment from @paddy - could be a root of loop problem

Comment: Great, I should be able to trouble shoot it the rest of the way, 
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious:

```
ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, head->getNext() );
```

You are passing `head->getNext()` into your new node.  I assume that parameter initialises the next-pointer in the new list node.  You should surely pass `NULL` rather than the second element of the list.

The other problem is that you modify `head` inside `insert_back`.  The `head` variable is a member of your class.  If you move the head all the way to the end of your list, you will lose your list.  Use a temporary variable to iterate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really don't care *at all* about performance, you probably want to add a `ListNode<Object> *tail;` to your `List` class. Keep it pointing to the last node in the list. When you need to add a new node, add the new node immediately after the one it points at, and update it to point to the new node you just added.